# How does fscanf() deal with double values?

Tags: c, double, scanf

In this question, my goal is to understand the `fscanf()`'s behavior when dealing with `double` type values. The language is C.

So, I had to read numbers in a file and store them in an array. 
The file is like this:

```
1600 1 2 3 4 5 1700 6 7 8 9 10 1800 11 12 13 14 15
```

I only need these numbers: `1660`, `1700` and `1800` (J=3).
And I have five numbers between them (I=5).

If I try to get these numbers as integers, the following code works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char filename[100];
    int *P; 
    int J = 3;
    int I = 5;  
    P = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * J);

    FILE *input_file;   
    iput_file = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    if (input_file == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Sorry, no such a file...\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < J; j++) {
        fscanf(input_file, "%d", &P[j]);
        printf("%d ", P[j]);
        for (int skip = 0; skip < I; ++skip) {
            fscanf(input_file, "%d");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, if I try to get them as `double`, like this, it doesn't work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char filename[100];
    double *P;  
    int J = 3;
    int I = 5;  
    P = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * J);

    FILE *input_file;   
    input_file = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    if (input_file == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Sorry, no such a file...\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < J; j++) {
        fscanf(input_file, "%lf", &P[j]);
        printf("%lf ", P[j]);
        for (int skip = 0; skip < I; ++skip) {
            fscanf(input_file, "%lf");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Actually, when I run it, I have the output `1600.000000`, then the program stops, with no errors, as if nothing went wrong.

Thinking and testing for some hours, I came up with the following solution. That is, put the values I don't need in a trash variable. Then, inside the second for, I edited the `fscanf` to

```
fscanf(input_file, "%lf", &trash);
```

And it worked just fine.

So, why the first code worked and the second didn't? How come it was okay with integers, and not with double? Is it something related to memory?

Comment: By default, `%f` or `%lf` in `printf()` and friends prints 6 decimal places (all zero if need be), exactly as you show.  So, it works correctly.  Use `%.0f` or `%g` (or `%.0lf` or `%lg` if you prefer) to print no decimal places.

Comment: The first code only worked by accident — that's the beauty (or devilishness) of _undefined behaviour_.  Things can appear to work and that's OK; they can fail horribly and that's OK.  Both are acceptable responses to undefined behaviour.  And there is no sensible way to decide which is better; they're both bad, because they're both permissible responses to invoking undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
fscanf(input_file,"%lf");
```

Is undefined behavior, because you have a format string which commands the computer to write into...where?  You haven't given it any place to write!

Simply enable warnings as errors when compiling, and this sort of invalid code would never compile, saving you from all manner of problems:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror
```

Or:

```
clang -Weverything -Werror
```

Answer (score 1):

As you experimented, `fscanf(input_file, "%lf");` has undefined behavior. To skip a value, you can convert it into a temporary variable or you can use `fscanf`'s assignment suppression option specified with a `*` after the `%`:

```
fscanf(input_file, "%*lf");
```

Note also that you should test the return values of `fscanf()` to detect invalid input and avoid undefined behavior in such cases. `fscanf()` returns the number of successful conversions.